# Rails validation -- error is generated , but record is still saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have models order.rb , line_items.rb -- where line_item is belongs to order. I've added custom validations, as such **an order should only have line_items all with same merchant_id**

My question is : it seems the validation is working fine -- i am able to get the error whenever it is violated, but "line_item" records are still saved in any situation. Any idea?

**Order.rb**

```
validate_on_update :only_one_merchant

def only_one_merchant
        merchants = []
        for line_item in self.line_items
          merchants << line_item.product.merchant_id
        end
        merchants = merchants.uniq
        errors.add(:line_items, "You could only order from one same merchant at time")  if  merchants.length > 1
    end
```

**Order.rb**  adding line_item

```
  current_item = LineItem.new(:quantity => quantity)
  current_item.variant = variant
  current_item.price   = variant.price
  self.line_items << current_item
```

Answer (score 0):

[`validate_on_update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#M001393) will check validation only when you update any record to validate the record in anycondition use [`validate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#M001391)

Chnage

```
validate_on_update :only_one_merchant
```

to

```
validate :only_one_merchant
```

& Check if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

```
validate :only_one_merchant

def only_one_merchant
        merchants = []
        for line_item in self.line_items
          merchants << line_item.product.merchant_id
        end
        merchants = merchants.uniq
        errors.add(:line_items, "You could only order from one same merchant at time")  if  merchants.length > 1
    end
```

It will solve your problem first these function call and then update

Comment: hi thanks for your response, but i am not clear.. can you rephrase it? thanks